# datagen.flow_from_directory function

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am using fer2013 dataset, and when I am using datagen.flow_from_directory function, it doesn't find all the images from the directory.

Here's my code

```
IMAGE_SIZE = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 64

train_data_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/FER2013/Training"
validation_data_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/FER2013/PublicTest"


datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, 
    validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    subset='training')

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    subset='validation')
```

Here's the result.

```
Found 22921 images belonging to 7 classes.
Found 714 images belonging to 7 classes.
```

I don't have an err per se, but in the directory folder I have 28000+ images and in PublicTest 3000+ so, why it finds me only 22921 and 714 insted of my actual number of images?

Comment: I would recommend you to go through this page. Try to understand how this method read images and set different classes to them. Read from start to understand the directory structure.  https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method

Comment: Thank for your sugestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have a separate directory for training and a separate directory for validation images. Each should have 7 sub directories one for each class and named identically in training and validation directories. In the data generator you set the validation_split=0.2. This is going to take your training images and dedicate 80% of them to training and 20% to validation. So roughly 28000 X .8 = 22400. Since you have a separate validation directory already you should set the split=0. That way all the images in the training directory will be used for training. With the validation_split=0 you do not need to specify subset in the flow_from_directory methods. Feed both the the train_generator and val_generator into model.fit.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine now. I am new to this and your explanation helped me a lot to understand such basic knowledge.

Comment: most welcome we all start out confused but in time you will become an expert